# NSRangeException with NSArray objectAtIndex, index beyond bounds

Tags: ios, crash, runtime-error

Can anyone let me know what the following error means in iOS Objective-C:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (13) beyond bounds (13)'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that your index is not within the valid range for your array. Your array has 13 elements and you are trying to access the 14th element. In C, indexes start at 0, so arrays have indexes that are valid from 0 to length - 1.

This is typically caused by an [off by one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_by_one_error).

Comment: Thanks a lot jason....

i solved my problem....u were right i was trying to access 14th element,which was not there


thanks a lot